# Java 'Write the code necessary to "left rotate" their values:'

Tags: java

I've tried a lot of combinations and have searched on the web for something useful but unfortunately I've found nothing useful.

This is for my homework. Only question I cannot answer out of 69 questions.

Question:

Four integer variables, pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4 have been declared and initialized. Write the code necessary to "left rotate" their values: for each variable to get the value of the successive variable, with pos4 getting pos1's value.

Example that I've tried:

```
int tempP1 = pos1;
int tempP2 = pos2;
int tempP3 = pos3;
int tempP4 = pos4;

pos4 = tempP1;
pos3 = tempP2;
pos2 = tempP3;
pos1 = tempP4;
```

What it shows me:

```
    Remarks:
     ⇒     Your code had an error during execution

More Hints:
     ⇒     Are you sure you want to use: tempP1
     ⇒     Are you sure you want to use: tempP2
     ⇒     Are you sure you want to use: tempP3

Problems Detected:
     ⇒     pos1 has wrong value
     ⇒     pos3 has wrong value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pos4 = tempP1;
pos2 = tempP3;
pos3 = tempP4;
pos1 = tempP2;
```

Sounds right?

Answer (score 2):

```
int tempP1 = pos1; 
int tempP2 = pos2; 
int tempP3 = pos3; 
int tempP4 = pos4; 

pos4 = tempP1; 
pos3 = tempP4; 
pos2 = tempP3; 
pos1 = tempP2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int tmp = pos1;
pos1 = pos2;
pos2 = pos3;
pos3 = pos4;
pos4 = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code would be :
`pos4=tempP1;
pos3=tempP4;
pos2=tempP3;
pos1=tempP2;`

Answer (score 0):

You can condense your code better by only declaring a single temp value rather than creating four different `tempValue`s:

```
int tempValue = 0;


tempValue = pos1;

pos1 = pos2;

pos2 = pos3;

pos3 = pos4;

pos4 = tempValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int a=pos4;
int b=pos3;
int c=pos2;
pos4=pos1;
pos3=a;
pos2=b;
pos1=c;
```